# How can i get five seconds of data appended to the end of file?

Tags: shell-script

suppose if a shell script appends a data to a file.txt like

```
1...........
2...........
3.............
4.............
5..............
```

Now i want another script that could check the fresh data appended to file.txt within five seconds
not the complete data.

I don't know if there is any otpion for `tail -f` which shows complete data.

for understanding something like `tail -5 file.txt` where -5 is not number of lines
but number no seconds.

NOTE : I don't want to miss any data each time it should give me the data from where it left
the last time.This is important.

Comment: It sounds like `logtail` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

[`retail`](http://www.ranum.com/security/computer_security/code/) is a *stateful* `tail`. It records the inode number and file size after each invocation, the next invocation picks up where it left off (optionally dealing with rotated files too, which is why the inode is recorded).

```
while true; do 
    retail myfile.log
    sleep 5
done
```

Unless the file data itself contains timestamps (it might, if it's via syslog) or some monotonic increasing ID, you must have some external state, `retail` uses the file size.

Assuming the file is only ever appended-to, and flushed line-by-line, `retail` will not loose data. It should also should be more reliable than inspecting timestamps within the data, unless they have high precision (e.g. µs or better precision).

`retail` is written in C, and seems similar to @Ulrich Dangel's suggestion of `logtail`. There appear to be two distinct versions of that, both implemented in perl, neither of which I've used:

- http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/logtail/
- http://logcheck.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You could extract last 5 **lines** from the script, with `tail -n 5` but only the last change in a file is ever timestamped, there is no timestamp per each change. If you want to retrieve last *n* seconds, you must store them separately yourself.

You could quantify your data.
Say, the script writing does, in main loop create a function that will launch once a second:

```
 CSEC=`date +%S`
 if [ "x$CSEC" != "x$SAVEDSEC" ] ; then
    mv f4.txt f5.txt
    mv f3.txt f4.txt
    mv f2.txt f3.txt
    mv f1.txt f2.txt

    echo $BUFFER > f1.txt
    BUFFER=
    SAVEDSEC=$CSEC
 fi
```

and in place where it writes data, e.g. with `echo`, it appends it to the buffer too.

```
echo $DATA >file.txt
BUFFER=$BUFFER$DATA
```

(and writes are stored in the $BUFFER instead of written to 'file.txt`)

In this case your script could do `cat f?.txt` to retrieve last 5 seconds of data.

Of course, pay attention to locking. If one script reads right in the middle of another script's disk operation, the data will be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

This should do exactly what you'd like....

```
#!/bin/bash

#This is the file we want to capture data from
TAILFILE=/path/to/input.txt

#This is the file we want to append to
OUTFILE=/path/to/output.txt

#How many seconds we want to tail the file
SECONDS=5

tail -F $TAILFILE >> $OUTFILE &
PID=$!
sleep $SECONDS
kill $PID
```