# I am trying to fetch the logs for last five minutes through a script

Tags: awk, logs, timestamps

I have a output log file which will be continuously appended and I am planning to have a script (runs for every 5 min) to retrieve the last 5 min data from of the output log.

Sample data from the output log file:

```
2015-10-29 09:19:39,630 INFO line1 of log  
2015-10-29 09:21:39,630 INFO line2 of log
2015-10-29 09:22:39,630 INFO line3 of log
2015-10-29 09:23:39,630 INFO line4 of log
2015-10-29 09:24:39,630 INFO line5 of log
2015-10-29 09:25:39,630 INFO line6 of log
```

If i am running my script at 09:25 it should capture last 5 lines and send to a separate output file.

Comment: This question covers a similar problem: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96276/how-can-i-get-five-seconds-of-data-appended-to-the-end-of-file

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need:

```
five_min=$( date -d "5 minutes ago" +"%F %T" )
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ "$five_min" < "$line" ]] && echo "$line"
done < output.log
```

---

So, it's a huge file. Then use `tac` to output the file from the bottom first:

```
five_min=$( date -d "5 minutes ago" +"%F %T" )
tac output.log | while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ "$five_min" < "$line" ]] && echo "$line"
done | tac
```

The `while` command, just like other languages, executes it's body while the condition is true. In POSIX shells, the "condition" of the `if` and `while` commands is itself a command. The "truth" of the "condition" is that the command exits with a zero exit status. It is very important to realize that the words `[` and `[[` are actually commands, not just syntax (from a bash shell type `help [[` and `help [`)

In this answer, the condition is `IFS= read -r line` which is the canonical way to read a line from a file, and keep all whitespace and backslash sequences intact. `read` will return with a non-zero exit status if there's nothing more to read from it's input stream. In my first response, I redirected the contents of the log file to the standard input of the `while` command, and `read` will read that data.

Comment: Thanks for your response..! The output log file is so huge so i just want to read the file from bottom and also is there any way we can achieve it through AWK command and also i am new to these scripting so can you help me in understanding the While command

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#To get previous 5 minutes logs from now(IST)
d1=$(date –date="-5 min" +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N')
d2=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N') #Added missing closing parenthesis

awk -v d1="$d1" -v d2="$d2" '$0 > d1 && $0 < d2 || $0 ~ d2' /var/log/<file_name >  > /var/log/$<new_file_name>
```